# How can I kill my iPhone when my location service is turned off?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, find-my-iphone

My iPhone 5 was stolen and my location service was turned off but I have Find My iPhone enabled. I have been trying to put my iPhone on lost mode but it appears to be offline. Is there any way I can track it or kill the iPhone perhaps?

Comment: Sometimes it helps by simply calling your number, you newer know there might be a honest person on the other end and will return it.

Answer (score 1):

If the iPhone has no power, there is nothing you can do as it cannot be found.
Find My Iphone only works with an iPhone turned on.

You could check regularly if they **power on** the iPhone, you can put it on the loud sound or clean it remotely. Offline/Without power there is nothing you can do.

If your iPhone was running iOS7 and iCloud is enabled the thieves cannot restore the iPhone, so they cannot sell it.